# Starting a thread with a button

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm programming a small android app in Java/eclipse.
In one part of my app i need a thread, as i build in the following way:

```
 protected void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
 // we're going to simulate real time with thread that append data to the graph
 new Thread(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
     // we add 100 new entries
     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
           addEntry();
         }
       });

       // sleep to slow down the add of entries
       try {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         // manage error ...
       }
     }
   }
  }).start();
 }
```

Evertything works fine so far. But now i want to start that thread not automatically. I want to handle ".start()" with a button. 
How can i realize it?
I'm very new to Java and Android.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: read documentation on asynctask in android

Comment: Thread.sleep on the UI thread sounds like a bad idea....

Comment: then dont this thread thing in resume do it in a separate method and call that method on button click

Comment: You can create a `Thread` instance  `Thread t = new Thread(....)` and start this thread when a button is pressed `t.start()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler with Runnable instead of your Thread idea, Check out the following code, it server your purpose,

```
private Handler broadcastHandler;
private Runnable broadcastRunnable;

protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();

broadcastRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    // Your UI related operations 
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
             public void run() {
                addEntry();
            }
         });

    // Add some delay 
    broadcastHandler.postDelayed(broadcastRunnable, 1000);
    }
}



public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    broadcastHandler.postDelayed(broadcastRunnable, 1000);
}
```